# Sql query to find date period between multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with three columns (City_Code | Start_Date | End_Date). 
Suppose i have the following data:

```
New_York|01/01/1985|01/01/1987
Paris|02/01/1987|01/01/1990 
San Francisco|02/01/1990|04/01/1990
Paris|05/01/1990|08/01/1990 
New_York|09/01/1990|11/01/1990 
New_York|12/01/1990|19/01/1990 
New_York|20/01/1990|28/01/1990
```

I would like to get the date period for which someone lived in the last city of his residence. In this example that is New_York(09/01/1990-28/01/1990) using only sql. I can get this period by manipulating the data with java , but is it possible to do it with plain sql?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What database product and version?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the first and last date of residence by city using this:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 City_Code, MIN(Start_Date), Max(End_Date)
 FROM Table
 GROUP BY City_Code
 ORDER BY Max(End_Date) desc
```

but, the problem is that the start date will be the first date of residence in the city in question.

Comment: +1 for getting close and to move this answer to the top of the list. Now you need to account for the contiguous entries. If this is SQL Server then a CTE may be in order.

Comment: The database used is oracle 10g.

Answer (score 1):

For 10g you don't have the option of SELECT TOP n so you must be a little creative.

```
WITH last_period
AS
(SELECT city, moved_in, moved_out, NVL(moved_in-LEAD(moved_out, 1) OVER (ORDER BY city), 0) AS lead
FROM periods
WHERE city = (SELECT city FROM periods WHERE moved_out = (SELECT MAX(moved_out) FROM periods)))
SELECT city, MIN(moved_in) AS moved_in, MAX(moved_out) AS moved_out
FROM last_period
WHERE lead >= 0
GROUP BY city;
```

This works for the example dataset that you have given.  It could stand some optimisation for a large dataset but gives you a working example, tested on Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0):

If it's MySQL, you can easily use

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date)) AS `diff_in_secs`
```

Having time difference in seconds you go any further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can use the DateDiff() function

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

**EDIT**

I don't know Oracle but I did find [this article](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ#How_does_one_get_the_time_difference_between_two_date_columns.3F)

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, couldn't you use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 City_Code, Start_Date + "-" + End_Date 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY enddate DESC
```

That would get the date period and city with the latest end date.
This is assuming you are trying to just find the city where the person most recently lived, formatted with a dash.

Comment: Thanks bobs. This is my first attempt at an answer, so I'm still learning how to post correctly.  My goal is to get enough reputation to be able to vote up some solutions to other problems that have helped me.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is Oracle, you can simply subtract the end date and start date to get the number of days in between.

```
Select City_Code, (End_Date - Start_Date) Days
From MyTable
Where Start_Date =  (
                        Select Max( T1.Start_ Date )
                        From MyTable As T1
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  MAX(t.duration) 
FROM (
       SELECT 
          (End_Date - Start_Date) duration 
       From 
           Table
) as t
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate only the last period length for the last city of residence, then it's probably something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  City_Code,
  End_Date - Start_Date AS Days
FROM atable
ORDER BY Start_Date DESC
```

But if you mean to include all the periods the person has ever lived in a city that happens to be their last city of residence, then it's a bit more complicated, but not too much:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  City_Code,
  SUM(End_Date - Start_Date) AS Days
FROM atable
GROUP BY City_Code
ORDER BY MAX(Start_Date) DESC
```

But the above solution most probably returns the last city information only after it calculates the data for all cities. Do we need that? Not necessarily, so maybe we should use another approach. Maybe like this:

```
SELECT
  City_Code,
  SUM(End_Date - Start_Date) AS Days
FROM atable
WHERE City_Code = (SELECT TOP 1 City_Code FROM atable ORDER BY Start_Date DESC)
GROUP BY City_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm short on time - but this feels like you could use the window function `LAG` to compare to the previous row and retain the appropriate begin date from that row when the city changes, and dont change it when the city is the same - this should correctly preserve the range.